# Pitch Calculation Error via Autocorrelation Method

Tags: r, audio, signal-processing, pitch

- Aim : Pitch Calculation
- Issue : The calculated pitch does not match the expected one. For instance, the output is approx. 'D3', however the expected output is 'C5'.
- Source Sound : https://freewavesamples.com/1980s-casio-celesta-c5

#### Source Code

```
library("tuneR")
library("seewave")

#0: Acquisition of sample sound
snd_smpl = readWave(paste("~/Music/sample/1980s-Casio-Celesta-C5.wav"), 
                                    from = 0, to = 1, units = "seconds")
dur_smpl = duration(snd_smpl)
len_smpl = length(snd_smpl)

#1 : Pre-Processing Stage

#1.1 : Application of Hanning Window
n = 1:len_smpl
han_win = 0.5-0.5*cos(2*pi*n/(len_smpl-1))
wind_sig = han_win*snd_smpl@left

#2.1 : Auto-Correlation Calculation
rev_wind_sig = rev(wind_sig)    #Reversing the windowed signal

acorr_1 = convolve(wind_sig, rev_wind_sig, type = "open")
# Obtaining the 2nd half of the correlation, to simplify calculation
n = 2*len_smpl-1 
acorr_2 = (1/len_smpl)*acorr_1[len_smpl:n]

#2.2 : Note Calculation
min_index = which.min(acorr_2)
print(min_index)
fs = 44100              
fo = fs/min_index #To obtain fundamental frequency

print(fo)
print(notenames(noteFromFF(fo)))
```

#### Output

```
> print(min_index)
[1] 37
> fs = 44100                
> fo = fs/min_index 
> print(fo)
[1] 1191.892
> print(notenames(noteFromFF(fo)))
[1] "d'''"
```

The entire calculation is performed in the **Time Domain**.
I'm currently using autocorrelation as a base to understand more about Pitch Detection & Analysis. I've tried to analyse the sample with 'Audacity' and the result is 'C5'. Hence, I'm wondering where actually the issue is.
Can you all help me find it?

Also, there are a few but important doubts:

1. How small should actually my analysis window be (20ms, 1s,..)?
2. Will reinforcement of the Autocorrelation Algorithm with AMDF and other similar algorithms make this Pitch Detection module more robust?

Answer (score 1):

This whole analysis seems not correct. You should not use windowing in time domain analysis.

Attached a short solution in the python language; you can use it as pseudocode

```
from soundfile import read
from glob import glob
from scipy.signal import correlate, find_peaks
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, show, xlim, title, xlabel
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

name = glob('*wav')[0]
samples, fs = read(name)

corr = correlate(samples, samples)
corr = corr[corr.size / 2:]
time = np.arange(corr.size) / float(fs)
ind = find_peaks(corr[time < 0.002])[0]

plot(time, corr)
plot(time[ind], corr[ind], '*')
xlim([0, 0.005])
title('Frequency = {} Hz'.format(1 / time[ind][0]))
xlabel('Time [Sec]')
show()
```

[image]